# progress bar countdown doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css

Hello i'm trying to put a progress bar countdown using the code bellow

```js
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
  var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
  $element.find('div').animate({
    width: progressBarWidth
  }, 500).html(timeleft + " seconds to go");
  if (timeleft > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
    }, 1000);
  }

};
progress(20, 20, $('#progressBar'));
```

```css
#progressBar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #0A5F44;
}

#progressBar div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 22px;
  /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle     aligned */
  width: 0;
  background-color: #CBEA00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progressBar">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

but it doesn't work , when a refresh the page i see only "20 seconds to go" without the bar in background and i can't find out what's the problem 
please can u tell me what are the possible causes of this problem ?

Comment: Any error messages in console? Where are you calling this function `progress`?

Comment: Where is the function that triggers/calls `progress() ` with the arguments?

Comment: no error messages in console

Comment: this is the function that triggers/calls progress() with the arguments
    progress(20, 20, $('#progressBar'));                                                                               i just forgot to add it

Comment: Your code (with the function call) [seems to work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/10wdv99r/). After you question edit you can even see the code working fine.... what is your problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

That can be, because Javascript is loaded completely new each time you refresh the page so will time left initiated to the same value.
You could use a cookie or phase the Value with i.e. PHP.

Answer (score -1):

edit the javascript in this:

```
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
  var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $($element).width() / timetotal;
  $($element).find('div').animate({
    width: progressBarWidth
  }, 500).html(timeleft + " seconds to go");
  if (timeleft > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
    }, 1000);
  }
};
```

heres the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/an1r77uo/

Comment: What have you even changed?

Comment: $element to $($element)

Comment: I see... that won't fix the problem. Mostly because there isn't a problem to fix. But the function call does the part of creating the JQuery object (hence the $prefix for the variable name, to indicate it is a JQuery object already)

Comment: ok but using the same code that he used and calling the function it doesn't work as well. after I made the modifications it works. if you see the jsfiddle link, the script works so why you have to downvote

Comment: It *does* work already. Run the code in the question and it works just fine. The reason your modifications work is because *you* are calling the function incorrectly, you are not calling it the same way the OP is in the question